# How would this be written without the > sign?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How would this code be written without the `>` symbol?

https://jsfiddle.net/rxhckemL/

How would that be done?

I wanted to know how the code would be written without the `>` symbol/sign.
That is all I am trying to do in the code.

It is able to be done, right?

**css**

```
   .fence>div {
      position: absolute;
      /*top: 0;*/
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      /*width: 100%;*/
      height: 0.55%;
      /*height: 2px;*/
      background: green;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(1) {
      top: 10%;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(2) {
      top: 20%;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(3) {
      top: 30%;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(4) {
      top: 40%;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(5) {
      top: 50%;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(6) {
      top: 60%;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(7) {
      top: 70%;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(8) {
      top: 80%;
    }
    
    .fence>div:nth-child(9) {
      top: 90%;
    }
```

**html**

```
   <div class="fence">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
   </div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 642px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0px #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><path stroke="rgb(113, 121, 126)" d="m10 .15-4.85 4.85 4.85 4.85v.15h-.13l-4.86-4.86-4.86 4.86h-.15v-.14l4.87-4.86-4.87-4.87v-.13h.15l4.86 4.86 4.85-4.86h.14z"/></svg>');
}

.fence>div {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 0.55%;
  background: green;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 40%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 50%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(6) {
  top: 60%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(7) {
  top: 70%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(8) {
  top: 80%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(9) {
  top: 90%;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  animation: fan-spin 8s linear;
}

@keyframes fan-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.cross::before,
.cross::after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
}

.cross::before /*horizontal*/{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 2.8%;
  /*height: 10px;*/
}

.cross::after /*vertical*/{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*width: 10px;*/
  width: 1.5%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
 <div class="outer">
   <div class="curtain ">
     <div class="ratio-keeper">
       <div class="fence">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>

       <div class="fan">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="76 130 381 381">
           <path fill="#000100" stroke="#000" d="m166.3352 168.6294c5.5396 2.4448 45.2339 54.394 72.7499 91.0151-9.1901-44.8757-21.7959-109.0279-19.9558-114.796 4.1462-12.9949 33.7039-13.5172 41.5845-13.7579 7.8827-.2415 37.4165-1.5221 42.3488 11.1948 2.1872 5.6436-6.4773 70.4506-12.9142 115.8007 25.2309-38.2323 61.6818-92.5089 67.0612-95.2865 12.119-6.2568 33.3898 14.2749 39.1337 19.6768 5.7424 5.402 27.5341 25.3815 22.0294 37.859-2.4441 5.5389-54.3954 45.2354-91.0172 72.7506 44.8757-9.1901 109.0293-21.7959 114.7974-19.9559 12.9927 4.1442 13.5193 33.7032 13.7586 41.5838.2422 7.8819 1.5221 37.4165-11.192 42.3473-5.6471 2.1894-70.4541-6.4765-115.8049-12.9127 38.2323 25.2323 92.5081 61.6783 95.2871 67.0605 6.2581 12.1175-14.2742 33.3877-19.6776 39.133-5.4027 5.7432-25.3815 27.5341-37.8563 22.0279-5.5396-2.4434-45.2361-54.3961-72.7534-91.0143 9.1901 44.8757 21.7952 109.0287 19.9551 114.7953-4.1434 12.9934-33.7026 13.5157-41.5852 13.7586-7.8799.24-37.4165 1.5221-42.3431-11.1936-2.1887-5.6464 6.4779-70.4541 12.9133-115.8071-25.2323 38.2323-61.6824 92.5124-67.0639 95.2908-12.1169 6.256-33.3891-14.2728-39.1337-19.6754-5.7432-5.4027-27.5313-25.383-22.0251-37.8578 2.4434-5.5396 54.394-45.2339 91.0136-72.7526-44.8764 9.1908-109.0266 21.7944-114.7967 19.9566-12.9934-4.1434-13.5171-33.7025-13.7586-41.5852-.2407-7.8806-1.5221-37.4165 11.1963-42.346 5.6443-2.1879 70.4498 6.4752 115.8 12.9121-38.233-25.2316-92.5081-61.6783-95.2865-67.0612-6.256-12.1169 14.2748-33.3913 19.6768-39.1337 5.4006-5.7438 25.3794-27.5333 37.8584-22.0272z" /></svg>

       </div>
       <div class="cross"></div>

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain your question?

Comment: You mean, the Play button and the playing container should not be wrap with container, it should be in separate elements. When we click on the play button it should activate the respective playing container.Is correct?

Comment: _"How would that be done?"_ - first of all, please explain _why_ should that be done? The `.fence` element in your example HTML code only has div children, not even any descendants further down than that - so this should already select the desired elements. What actual _problem_ are you trying to fix here?

Comment: I wanted to know how the code would be written without the > symbol/sign. That is all I am trying to do in the code. It is able to be done, right?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the `>`?

Comment: I just wanted to know how it would be written without the > symbol/sign.

Comment: In general, it _wouldn't_ - because that `>` has special meaning for the selector. It can be removed (i.e., be replaced by whitespace) in this specific case here, because for the given DOM structure, it makes no difference. But to ask the question how to remove it _in general_, makes little sense. Usually it will have been deliberately used to achieve something specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question right. But if all you want is to write the code without `>`, the simplest answer would be: Leave out the `>` and use a whitespace instead:

I.E. instead of

```
.fence>div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10%;
}
```

write

```
.fence div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10%;
}
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/y6tmh3wL/

Of course, in css using `>` or   is something different. And by no means you can substitute any `>` with   in a given css code. But in this specific example it leads to the same visual result. Is this what you wanted?

For a very brief explanation:

- `>` selects direct children
- also selects nested children

See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp